# Translate a view and get click event

Tags: android, android-animation

First of all please excuse me if this question is already asked.

I am new to android animations.

I want a view lets say an Image View (with animation i.e,smooth movement) to permanently move one position to some other position of the screen lets say if current **X co-ordinate  to X+50 and similarly Y co-ordinate to Y+50**. I was able to move using XML translate animation file but not able to get click event after that.**I am able to get click event at the original position in the layout not from the translated position**.

Can anyone guide me to right track?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `ObjectAnimator` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do animation programatically. Try this code. It may help

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta);
            translateAnimation.setDuration(500);
            translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                     //before animation
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    //after animation

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            imageView.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

Answer (score 3):

The Animations you use are deprecated.. I show an example of ObjectAnimator class... And this sample is in a Fragment, so i write the whole onCreateView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_screen, container, false);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    ObjectAnimator translationY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "translationY", 100);
    translationY.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    ObjectAnimator translationX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "translationX", 100);
    translationX.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();
    as.playTogether(translationX, translationY);
    as.setDuration(2000);
    as.start();


    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int sum = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked: " +  sum++, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably using `view.startAnimation();`. Key here is do your `animation` programatically.

do

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (this.context, R.anim.your_translate_animation);
animation .setStartOffset (2000);
yourView.startAnimation (animation);

animation.setAnimationListener (new AnimationListener () {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart (Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat (Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) {

        //do you click functionality here...

    }
});
```

P.S. If you want to click view programtically

do

```
yourView.performClick();
```

Comment: Thanks Murtaza Hussain... I did the same... I dont want programatically invoke click event. The view is moving fine but the click event after translation is not getting..  the view is still in the original position and from there i'm getting the click event.

Comment: ohhh you mean you are unable to click ?

Comment: use `animation.setFillAfter (true);` after `animation.startAnimation()`

Comment: specially the translate xml file